# Angular 2 Yfiles for HTML - OrthogonalEdgeEditingContext

Tags: html, angular, typescript, yfiles

I'm working on a webApp in an **Angular 2** application. I have integrated **Yfiles for HTML** but I need to force edge paths to only have **right angles**.
This feature is possible with the **orthogonalEdgeEditingContext** function.

I have read the documentation here: [documentation](https://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtml/#/dguide/interaction-support#interaction-orthogonal_edge_editing) but this function doesn't work on Angular. Is it well implemented in angular?

`graphEditorInputMode.orthogonalEdgeEditingContext = new yfiles.input.OrthogonalEdgeEditingContext();`

I found an other example here : [example](https://www.hulinks.co.jp/support/yfiles/data/tips_24/2_BusinessProcess/BusinessProcessDiagramComponent.as) je me suis inspiré de cet exemple pour créer la définition suivante:

```
var mode = this.graphComponent.inputMode = new yfiles.input.GraphEditorInputMode();
var OrthoEditing = mode.orthogonalEdgeEditingContext = new yfiles.input.OrthogonalEdgeEditingContext();
OrthoEditing.enabled = true;
```

But when running the app I have this error:

> ERROR TypeError: yfiles.input.GraphEditorInputMode is not a constructor

If you have some recommendations for any assistance is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second example that you link is "ActionScript" - this is Flash and it uses a slightly different and older API than the current version of yFiles for HTML, which is JavaScript/TypeScript based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably means that you haven't loaded the right (or all) UMD modules and `yfiles.input.GraphEditorInputMode` is still `undefined` (and thus not a constructor). Make sure you have loaded the corresponding class definitions before instantiating the types.

What makes you think that the documented functionality is not working in Angular specifically? Basically angular still is just JavaScript - it just adds lots of layers of code on top of everything and makes everything a lot harder ;-) - but still what works in a simple JavaScript application should also work in an angular environment.

<sup>That being said: as a customer or evaluator you get support from yWorks directly and sharing large amounts of code is probably not something you will do on SO.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I forgot to add "./lib/yfiles/impl/graph-input.js" in my .angular-cli.json to add this module. Now, the app works well but I need to find why my edge paths are not orthogonal even with this setting class.